# Pam.d reporting incorrect $RHOST in script

Tags: ssh, pam

I've implemented a login-notify script in /etc/ssh

The script will notify me via Microsoft Teams when there is a login to my VM, with the user, host and service

However - it appears the rhost is sometimes behind
For example a user ssh'd onto the machine at 8:06, the ip reported was mine, and not his. 
Then at 10:06 i ssh'd onto the machine, and the ip reported was his and not mine - so it's as if the rhost is always one behind

Has anyone else had this issue? or know how to solve please?

EDIT - Here is the script

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$PAM_TYPE" != "close_session" ]; then
    host="`hostname`"
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"text\": \"SSH Login: User -'$PAM_USER' On - '$host' from $PAM_RHOST\"}" [MS_TEAMS_HOOK
fi
```

Comment: seems like a problem in your script. We can't be sure without reviewing your script. However It doesn't seems to be related to Ubuntu...

Comment: @Yaron - I have updated the question with the script - there is nothing going on in the script which would cause the delay, only $PAM_RHOST that is reporting the wrong IP

Comment: After it was updated this question looks OK to me.